# Posting data to PHP script and then process it

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, http-post, httprequest

I'm trying to make a HTTP POST request to my PHP script. However, it doesn't seem to be retrieving the request data.

To simulate a POST request, I used Request Maker and sent over a url of `http://php-agkh1995.rhcloud.com/lta.php` and a request data of `var1=65059`.
Using the default url in the `else` statement works perfectly fine but not the other

I'm suspecting the request headers to be the fault unless there's a major flaw in my code

**lta.php**

```
$stopid=$_POST['var1'];
$defurl = ""; // Default url

if(!empty($stopid)){
$defurl = 'http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusArrival?BusStopID=$stopid';
} else {
 $defurl = 'http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusArrival?BusStopID=83139';
}   

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => $defurl,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Ashton',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('AccountKey: ********', 'UniqueUserId: ******', 'accept: application/json')
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo($resp); // To test if data is displayed or not 
return $resp;
```

**Request headers sent**

```
POST /lta.php HTTP/1.1
Host: php-agkh1995.rhcloud.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Try isset instead of !empty

Comment: The single quote in the first url are preventing the variable replacement

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to test the existence of the POST variable

```
if(array_key_exists($_POST,'var1')){
    $stopid=$_POST['var1'];
    $defurl = "http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusArrival?BusStopID=$stopid";
} else { 
 ..
}
```

PS : if your `$defurl` is set to the else case value by default you don't even need the `else` clause

Comment: Ok, I've changed it to what you've suggested. However, it is now always going to the `else` case

Comment: What OS are you running ?

Comment: Windows. I'm running the script on PHP 5.4 on an OpenShift server

Comment: Try testing with `curl` or `wget` instead of request maker or create a dummy form to send the request

Comment: I would recommend create a dummy form, to be able to debug the request with the web inspector

Comment: Could you print the var value, instead of calling the web service  ? By adding a `print($_POST['var1']);exit;` after the test for testing

Comment: Alright, the dummy page successfully received exactly what I passed over. Still can't seem to isolate the problem in my actual script

Comment: Could you put the `else` clause like it was I wrote it ? close to the `if` closing brace

Comment: Ok, I threw the entire cURL POST into the else loop you specified above and it's working now. It just seems that `array_key_exists` always returns `false`